# How do I exclude/ignore specific file types/extensions with rmlint?

Tags: deduplication, specifications, exclude, ignore

I am trying to dedupe a labyrinthine directory, but I keep getting results for the contents of the items I want to match rather than the enclosing items, themselves, i.e. my results are full of things like '.css' & '.strings' files from unmatched '.app' bundles.

I can't restrict by recursive depth because there is no uniformity to the subfolders in the directory.

I want to tell rmlint to ignore '.nib' & 'icon?' & '.plist' etc. files & just give me the dupes for the enclosing '.app' or '.scptd' or '.action' etc. files.

Can I do this? How do I do this? Is there a better byte-by-byte comparison tool to do this with?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the "find" utility to exclude these files and then pipe the result to rmlint:

```
$ find /target/dir -type f ! -name '*.nib' ! -name '*.icon' ! -name '*.plist' | rmlint [options] -
```

The "! -name 'pattern'" tells find to exclude files matching 'pattern'.

The "-" option for rmlint means read the file list from stdin.